# Clicking on a row must redirect the page to another URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using a Datatable in my .Net MVC application. 
Currently I have implemented the following:

- The first column of the table is 'ID' and its data is clickable.
- Clicking on the data redirects the user to another page.
- The URL where the user is redirected is dependent on the ID being clicked. Hence each row has a unique URL.

Atop of this I have one condition applied which is as follows:

- There's another row named Status. It contains one of these values: Draft or Saved.
- So based on the value of Draft the URL to be redirected is decided.

Here's my current script:

```
"ajax":
   {
     "url": "/Request/Search/LoadData",
     "type": "POST",
     "datatype": "json",
     "data": function (d) {
       d.obj = searchFilters();
     },
   },
   "columns":
     [
       {
         "data": "RequestNo",
         "render": function (data, type,row, full, meta) {
           if (row.Status == "Draft") {
             return '<a href="/ChopRequest/Request?RequestId=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
           } else {
             return '<a href="/ChopRequest/ViewRequest/Index?id=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
           }
         }
       }
     ]
```

**So in this case the only option the user has is to click the data in the very first column. Instead I want the entire row to be clickable while preserving the above mentioned conditions.**

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect clicks in other cells and redirect browser to the link located in the first column of the same row.

For example:

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody td', function(){
   window.location = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) a').attr('href');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    
    $('#example').on('click', 'tbody td', function(){
       window.location = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) a').attr('href');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="//www.datatables.net">Tiger Nixon</a></td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```